# Why isn't there function to count Document Frequency (DF) in NLTK?

Tags: python, nltk

I am looking for a function to get the DF of certain term (meaning how many documents contain a certain word in a corpus), but I can't seem to find the function [here](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/text.html). The page only has function to get values of [tf, idf, and tf_idf](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.html#nltk.text.TextCollection). I am looking specifically for DF only. I copied the code below from the documentation,

`matches = len([True for text in self._texts if term in text])`

but I don't like the result it gives. For example if I have a list of strings and I am looking for the word `Pete`, it also includes the name `Peter` which is not I want. For example.

`texts = [['the', 'boy', 'peter'],['pete','the', 'boy'],['peter','rabbit']]`

So I am looking for `pete` which appears TWICE, but the code I showed above will tell you that there are THREE pete's because it also counts `peter`. How do I solve this? Thanks.

Comment: In your example `peter` occurs twice and `pete` just once

Comment: as a side note your first sublist does not have a comma between `boy` and `peter`, I didn't edit so you could notice

Comment: @erasmortg oops I didn't realize that. I just made the example on the spot. In fact I have my own list which is too long to post here. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: alright, how about the answer I posted?

Comment: Probably because it's not all that directly useful and if you really care you can get it from the idf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your description is incorrect. The expression you posted does indeed give 1, not 3, when you search for `pete` in `texts`:

```
>>> texts = [['the', 'boy', 'peter'],['pete','the', 'boy'],['peter','rabbit']]
>>> len([True for text in texts if 'pete' in text])
1
```

The only way you could have matched partial words is if your texts were not tokenized (i.e. if `texts` is a list of strings, not a list of token lists).

But the above code is terrible, it builds a list for no reason at all. A better (and more conventional) way to count hits is this:

```
>>> sum(1 for text in texts if 'pete' in text))
1
```

Comment: I think the OPer wants a stemmer/lemmatizer, magic mention-detection + entity-linking device that comes with a document frequency counter. Not sure why your answer is down voted but **this answer is correct**.

Comment: @alvas I don't know if you're being sarcastic, but I am certainly not asking for help on stemmer/lemmatization. Anyway, I think this is the answer I need. Thanks a lot @ alexis.

Comment: I didn't think @Anna was asking for too much! This is a question that was researched before asking, the question covers the "what have you tried" angle, but maybe the question got a little lost in the background info. Glad my answer helped sort it out!

Comment: I'm not being sarcastic. But when you need to match `pete` and `peter` as one, most probably you'll need a mention detection + entity-linking and normally that assumes a stemmer/lemmatizer too =) Mais non, the downvote by whoever was unnecessary ;P

Comment: Aha! :-) @alvas, read the question more carefully! Matching `pete` to `peter` is a (perceived) problem with the code, not a requested feature.

Comment: Ah! Perceived problem, okay misunderstood ;P

Comment: And by "perceived" I mean that the code doesn't actually have this behavior (cf. my answer).

Answer (score 1):

As for the question that you pose (Why (...)?) : I don't know.

As a solution to your example (noting that `peter` occurs twice and `pete` just once:

```
texts = [['the', 'boy', 'peter'],['pete','the', 'boy'],['peter','rabbit']]
def flatten(l):
    out = []
    for item in l:
        if isinstance(item, (list, tuple)):
            out.extend(flatten(item))
        else:
            out.append(item)
    return out

flat = flatten(texts)

len([c for c in flat if c in ['pete']])
len([c for c in flat if c in ['peter']])
```

Compare the two results

Edit:

```
import collections
def counts(listr, word):
    total = []
    for i in range(len(texts)):
        total.append(word in collections.Counter(listr[i]))
    return(sum(total))

counts(texts,'peter')
#2
```

Comment: hey, thanks for the answer. But I don't think that's what I specifically need. If I change the texts to `texts = [['the', 'boy', 'peter'],['pete','the', 'boy'],['peter','rabbit', 'peter']]` it will print that there are 3 'peter'. I probably should specify that `document frequency` is the number of documents a term appears. If in a document a certain term appears 100 times, it will only count as 1, not 100. Just like in my example, 'peter` appears in 2 documents, so df = 2 albeit appearing 3 times in 2 documents (here document is list). Hopefully it's clear enough? Thanks though

Comment: @AnnaRG edited the answer, see the second function, I believe this now gives the result you want

Comment: Thanks, it works. But sorry that I have to go with another answer as it's more efficient. But your code is good too.